# UTF8 to ASCII conversion in C#

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, encoding, json.net

I am aware that there is already a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352209/conversion-from-utf8-to-ascii), but unfortunately the top answer did not help me.

I want to `POST` some data to a RESTful web service via [Unity Webrequest](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html). As [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html) says,

> The data in `postData` will be escaped, then interpreted into a byte
>   stream via System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.

The data in `postData` is stored in JSON format. The remote web service will deserialize all incoming data using `NewtonSoft.Json`.

Unfortunately, the remote web service throws a `JsonReaderException`, with the message `"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: %. Path '', line 0, position 0."` That is because the posted data look something like this as a string (truncated):

> %7b%22LogType%22%3a%22Drill%22%2c%22Action%22%3a%22Started%22%2c%22Description%22%3a%22...

I tried to translate the incoming data from UTF-8 into ASCII before calling the `Newtonsoft.Json` library to deserialize it:

```
byte[] contentBytes = await Request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
string postContents = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.ASCII, contentBytes));
```

However, `JsonReaderException` is still thrown, because `postContents` still looks something like this:

> %7b%22LogType%22%3a%22Drill%22%2c%22Action%22%3a%22Started%22%2c%22Description%22%3a%22...

What should I do to ensure that the remote web service can successfully deserialize the data it receives?

Comment: I think your data became URL encode in transit.  Forget about ASCII, that would be just one more problem.

Comment: I would expect you could just cal `UrlDecode()` on it, but I'm at all confident in suggesting that's the best approach, in case there's a way to handle it earlier in the process...

Comment: `The data in postData will be escaped...` <-- that's the problem.  Just send it as an object and let the web server deal with it itself.

Comment: Post all the relevant C# code, client and server if possible.

Comment: Unity is not being helpful here by posting the body as an `x-www-form-urlencoded` type, which the server apparently is unwilling to interpret. From what I gather from the docs, you can't use the static convenience method and you'll need to construct an explicit `UnityWebRequest` instance and set the `uploadHandler` to a `RawUploadHandler` instance (assuming you can't modify the server code to handle a form instead).

Comment: @JeroenMostert When it comes to web requests, Unity is still in 2001 it seemed

Comment: There are many duplicates if you just search for "unity3d post JSON" : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38109658/unity-post-request-using-www-class-using-json | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45470315/unity-3d-call-post-api-with-json-request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you're receiving is [URL encoded](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).

For example:

- `%7b` is `{`
- `%22` is `"`
- `%3a` is `:`

So the start of the received URL encoded string is this:

`{"LogType":"Drill"`

which is clearly a valid JSON string.

So, what you need to do is to [url decode](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.urldecode?view=netframework-4.8) it to a regular JSON string, and then use JSON.NET to deserialize it.

Comment: Problem is that the OP is _sending_ this, the other side has to decode.

Comment: @HenkHolterman That comment doesn't make too much sense. The OP's code both sends and receives, it can be handled at any end

Comment: Actually it's not clear who owns that "remote web service". THe question does focus on the client though.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //url decode to byte[]
    byte[] bytes = HttpUtility.UrlDecodeToBytes(urlstring);
    //byte[] to jsonstring
    string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

classname decoded = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<classname>(json);
```