# Passing string data into another method and saved it into JSON file

Tags: php, unity-game-engine

here I want to save files into json. I use a php server. How do I pass the "data string" below on my json web?  I want to save all data such as position, depth, wind speed, temperature and flow. I think I need to pass the "data" into sendTextToFile.

```
    [Serializable]
    public class ShipData
    {

        public Vector2Int position;
        public float depth;
        public float windspeed;
        public float temperature;
        public float flow;

    }

    [SerializeField]
    private ShipData JSON_ShipData = new ShipData();


    public void SaveintoJson()
    {

        string data = JsonUtility.ToJson(JSON_ShipData, true);
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(Application.persistentDataPath + "/DataCenter.json", data);

        Debug.Log(data);
    }

    IEnumerator sendTextToFile()
    {
        //
        bool successful = true;

        //webform to use speaking with unity
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("Data", data.ToString());
       



        WWW www = new WWW("http://localhost/71/php/formunity.php", form);

        //take time to do this..
        yield return www;
        if (www.error != null)
        {
            successful = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log(www.text);
            successful = true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Make it `IEnumerator sendTextToFile(string data) { ... }` and then call it like `StartCorourine(sendTextToFile(data));`? Or afaik there is some overload for uploading a file via given path instead .. depending on your php implementation..

Comment: In general rather use [`UnityWebRequest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html) instead of the **obsolete** `WWW` class!

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38109658/unity-post-request-using-www-class-using-json